# How can i use Google’s Cloud Pub/Sub Real-Time Messaging Service in android

Tags: android, real-time, communication, google-cloud-pubsub

> I want develop a **guess game** where user can communicate with each
>   other like group/one to one conversation and it should be cross platfrom for both android and ios.

So i search on web and found these

- [**SendBird**](https://sendbird.com/)
- [**PubNub**](https://www.pubnub.com/)
- [**Pusher**](https://pusher.com/)

But my boss's insist to use google services for this so i find

- **[Google Cloud PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/)**: 
  A global service for real-time and reliable messaging and streaming data

but unfortunately i did't find any suitable demo or startup of **PubSub** with android instead i found **PubNub** [**here.**](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/0dfd8028b803332f5641adc909b1a26f87bd7ff1/android)

> So is there any resource to start with Google Cloud PubSub in android?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After exploring [**Google Cloud Pub/Sub Client Libraries docs**](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries)
>   provided **[Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java)** sample on their site.

Which states that **Android is not currently supported.**

[image]